# How to change multiple label's text color at the same time in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have multiple `Label`s inside a `Grid` which are places in different grid rows and columns. I want to change all the label's font color into just one color whenever I select a different theme color in my settings. At the moment I have the following code in C#:

```
correctLabel.TextColor = Color.Black;
textLabel.TextColor = Color.Black;
emptyLabel.TextColor = Color.Black;
detail1.TextColor = Color.Black;
detail2.TextColor = Color.Black;
detail3.TextColor = Color.Black;
```

As you can see, this code could be longer if I decided to add more `Label`s. Is there a way to do this in one line?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is already leading to the right assumption, you shouldn't do it per view element.

If you are able to use the 2.3 preview, there's built-in support for themes, [check out the docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/themes/).

Prior to 2.3 pre you can use `ControlTemplate`s, a nice sample can be found [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/app-theming-with-xamarin-forms-control-templates/).

**Edit:** If you're not aiming to theme the whole app, you can bind to a color in your view model of you are familiar with that and by changing that color, the label colors would adapt it. I guess maybe that comes closer to the one-line approach.